# Is there a limit to loudness?

Tags: acoustics

Is there any reason to believe that any measure of loudness (e.g. sound pressure) might have an upper boundary, similar to upper limit (c) of the speed of mass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's talk about the sound waves in the air first. Physically they are longitudinal waves of pressure. The bunch of air in one place will get compressed (in comparison with equilibrium state) and after that will expand, compressing the adjacent air and so on the wave propagates. These (single frequency) waves are essentially described by three numbers: the speed of propagation (called speed of sound; it depends on the type of the material and the temperature), the frequency of oscillation (determining the pitch), and the amplitude of oscillation.

It is the amplitude of oscillations which determines the loudness. So you are essentially asking whether there is any limit on amplitude of compression. Well, of course. At high enough pressures, the air would freeze even at normal temperatures. So this is the limit for air. Similar thing would happen with liquids: at certain pressures they would condense into solids. You could continue with phases of matter in this way and applying higher and higher pressures you would eventually end up with a black hole. That would be an ultimate limit.

But of course, in reality the limit is set by our engineering capabilities and I doubt it's possible to create sound waves that would be able to freeze air.

Comment: You've completely missed the effects of adiabatic compressional heating. You won't liquify the air by compression, its temperature rises with pressure, so it will remain gaseous, and the soundwave transitions into a shockwave. So it becomes an issue of symantics, is a shockwave a highamplitude soundwave, or is it something different? Of course the local soundspeed scales as the squareroot of temperature, so as the compression ratio of the shock increases its velocity increases as well.

Comment: Of course you can liquify it, but it's true that it will heat somewhat (depending on precise process used). I had intended to discuss also temperature dependence and other phenomena but apparently I forgot to mention it for some reason.

Comment: I really doubt it will liquify. Adiabatic heating is stronger than you imagine. For a perfect gas, T is proportional to density to the 2/3rds power, air has higher heat capacity, so at gamma =7/5ths it only increases at the .4 power of density. That still means a 300x increase in density implies a 10x increase in temperature. Can we get liquid phase on that curve, or will we end up much hotter than the triple point? These pressures are readily reachable via high explosives.

Comment: @Omega: I guess you meant critical point? Sure if the temperature got bigger than that there would no longer be a distinction between gas and liquid but the gas/liquid should still condense to a solid. But I have to admit, it's not clear to me whether at those pressures and temperatures other processes (like nuclear and eventually GR) wouldn't take over.

Comment: I'm dredging this up because it's a basic question I think we should get right. The fact that you mention black holes in an answer about sound in air is concerning. There are certain gases with high enough heat capacity to undergo liquefaction in lab conditions, but they do not include air. The limiting factor for a shock wave in air will be entropy produced by dissipation at the wavefront, which will tend to decrease the overpressure as the wave propagates. Your mention of "engineering capabilities" is also interesting, considering the loudest sounds recorded have not been anthropogenic.

Comment: @OmegaCentauri So is there a way to measure the Total Harmonic Distortion of a sine wave in air and use a threshold like 1% distortion to be the boundary between sound and shock waves?

Answer (score 13):

Yes - there is a sound pressure limit for *undistorted* sound. Over that limit we have a shock wave. It depends on the environmental pressure, but there is a theoretical limit to loudness which you can [find here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure_and_sound_pressure_levels).

The limit is basically equal to the pressure.

> Theoretical limit for undistorted sound at 1 atmosphere environmental pressure    101,325 Pa  ~194.094 dB
>
> The lower limit of audibility is therefore defined as 0 dB, but the upper limit is not as clearly defined. While 1 atm (191 dB) is the largest pressure variation an undistorted sound wave can have in Earth's atmosphere, larger sound waves can be present in other atmospheres, or on Earth in the form of shock waves.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't give any reference, though.  I assume the air behaves at least somewhat non-linearly near vacuum?  So a more realistic measurement would be the point at which the non-linearity of the air produces 1% distortion, for instance.

Comment: Perhaps interesting for getting an idea of what exceeding this theoretical upper limit of 194dB SPL might 'sound' like;I had come across that wikipedia page in search of an explanation for the 'rattling' sound you hear during rocket launches of for instance  NASA and SpaceX. I had always asumed the 'bad' audio was just the clipping recording equipment, but appearantly this 'rattling' is actually how such a launch sounds, and it is supposedly caused by exceeding the 194dB limit. A good example can be found here: https://youtu.be/WpWHXB4V7cs?t=100

Answer (score 1):

Well, the short answer is: there is, when the hydrodynamic approximation (that fluid is composed of small "fluid particles" i which real particles move in the reference frame of the "fluid particle" like in stationary fluid) breaks.

The upper bound can be approximated with wave amplitude equal to ambient pressure, so that the pressure is going down to 0 in wave minimas (this plus minus corresponds to cavitation); yet this corresponds to loudness of $\infty$dB.

Comment: "yet this corresponds to loudness of ∞dB."  No, it's 194 dB SPL.

Answer (score -2):

The only practical limit to sound-pressure might be when the medium were to be compressed into a black hole. Although I do not know about the sound-propagating features of black holes. Long before that the medium would come apart, f.e. into plasma.

After all, you compare two things: an upper limit of a speed with a power. How much power can you put into a particle to speed it up with *c* in mind?

PS: I'd rather not guess what kind of sound-generator would be necessary. One might ask the band "Disaster Area" (https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Hotblack_Desiato)

Comment: You'll reach a vacuum in the negative direction long before you reach a black hole in the positive direction.